# Match Merge in R

Tags: r, sas

I'm working on migrating some SAS programs into R, and I'm having a difficult time figuring out the best way to accomplish this seemingly simple bit of logic.

```
DATA HAVE;  
MERGE HAVE1  HAVE2;
BY ID;
RUN;
```

Example for Match merge is,

HAVE1:

```
ID  A   B   
10  1   2   
20  3   4   
30  5   6
```

HAVE2:

```
ID  C       
10  0       
30  1       
40  1
```

HAVE:

```
ID  A   B   C
10  1   2   0
20  3   4   .
30  5   6   1
40  .   .   1
```

Comment: With base R this is `merge(HAVE1, HAVE2)` or with dplyr `inner_join(HAVE1, HAVE2)`. R will automatically join by ID since that's the only column name common to both data frames.

Comment: I think you want `merge(HAVE1, HAVE2, all = TRUE)` or `outer_join(HAVE1, HAVE2)` to get the desired output.

Comment: Since you are not doing a many to many join the linked question will work.  But if you were doing a many to many join then the SAS merge code will behave differently than the default joins in R.

Comment: Thanks. All the above comments were helpful